# Simple Layout Edit on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change [this](http://cizgiaydinlatma.com/urunler/ray-spot-aydinlatma/) product category page's layout to 4 columns.

I want it to look like [this one](http://cizgiaydinlatma.com/aydinlatma-urunleri/).

The web site is on wordpress and support guy of the theme said i need to edit that code below.

All help will be appreciated, Thank you!

```
<?php

if( ! function_exists("rt_product_categories_shortcode") ){
    /**
     * Product Categories   
     * @param  array $atts 
     * @param  string $content
     * @return output
     */
    function rt_product_categories_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = null ) { 

        global $rt_list_atts, $rt_category;

        //defaults
        $rt_list_atts = shortcode_atts( array(  
            "id"                   => '',
            "class"                => '',
            "ids"                  => '',
            "list_layout"          => "1/3",
            "display_titles"       => "true",       
            "display_descriptions" => "true",       
            "display_thumbnails"   => "true",       
            "image_max_height"     => '',
            "crop"                 => '',
            'orderby'              => 'name',
            "order"                => "ACS",
            'parent'               => 0,
            'layout_style'         => ''
        ), $atts );

        extract( $rt_list_atts );
        ob_start();



    // Product Categories       
    $product_args = array(
        'type'         => 'post',
        'orderby'      => $orderby,
        'order'        => $order,
        'hide_empty'   => 0,
        'hierarchical' => 1,  
        'taxonomy'     => 'product_categories',
        'pad_counts'   => true,
        'include'      => $ids,
        'parent'        => empty( $parent ) ? 0 : $parent
    );  

    $product_categories = get_categories($product_args);

    //fix true false
    $rt_list_atts["display_titles"] = ! empty( $display_titles ) && $display_titles !== "false" ? "true" : "false";
    $rt_list_atts["display_descriptions"] = ! empty( $display_descriptions ) && $display_descriptions !== "false" ? "true" : "false";
    $rt_list_atts["display_thumbnails"] = ! empty( $display_thumbnails ) && $display_thumbnails !== "false" ? "true" : "false";
    $rt_list_atts["crop"] = ! empty( $crop ) && $crop !== "false" ? "true" : $crop;

    //id attr
    $id = ! empty( $id ) ? 'id="'.sanitize_html_class($id).'"' : "";     

    //item width percentage
    $list_layout = ! empty( $list_layout ) ? $list_layout : "1/3";

    //column count
    $column_count = rt_column_count( $list_layout );

    //category count
    $post_count = count( $product_categories );

    //layout style
    $add_holder_class = $list_layout == "1/1" ? "" : ( $layout_style == "grid" ? " border_grid fixed_heights" : " masonry" ) ;
    $add_holder_class .= " ".sanitize_html_class( $class );

    //column class
    $add_column_class = "product_item_holder ";
    $add_column_class .= rt_column_class( $list_layout );
    $add_column_class .= $layout_style == "masonry" ? " isotope-item" : "";

    //open the wrapper
    echo "\n".'<div '.$id.' class="product_holder product-showcase product-showcase-categories clearfix '.trim($add_holder_class).'" data-column-width="'. $column_count .'" >'."\n";

    $counter = 1;

    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category ) {

            $rt_category  = $category;

            //open row block
            if(  $layout_style != "masonry" && $list_layout != "1/1" && ( $counter % $column_count == 1 || $column_count == 1 ) ){
                echo '<div class="row clearfix">'."\n";
            }   

                echo $list_layout != "1/1" ? '<div class="col '.$add_column_class.'">'."\n" : "";
                get_template_part( 'product-contents/category-shortcode-content'); 
                echo $list_layout != "1/1" ? '</div>'."\n" : "";


            //close row block
            if( $layout_style != "masonry" && $list_layout != "1/1" && ( $counter % $column_count == 0 || $post_count == $counter ) ){
                echo '</div>'."\n";  
            }

        $counter++;

    }
    echo '</div>';  
    $output_string = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean(); 
    return $output_string;
}
}
add_shortcode('rt_product_categories', 'rt_product_categories_shortcode');
```

**category-shortcode-content.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product categories within loops.
 *
 * @author      RT-Themes
 * 
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $rt_list_atts, $rt_category;

extract( $rt_list_atts );

$tax_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$rt_category->term_id" );
$cat_image_id = is_array( $tax_meta ) && isset( $tax_meta["product_category_image"] ) && ! empty( $tax_meta["product_category_image"] ) ? $tax_meta["product_category_image"] : "";
$cat_image_url = "";
if( $cat_image_id ){
    $get_cat_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_image_id );
    $cat_image_url = is_array( $get_cat_image ) ? $get_cat_image[0] : "";
}

//image max height
$h = $crop == "true" ? $image_max_height : 10000;   

//Thumbnail dimensions
$w = rt_get_min_resize_size( $list_layout );    

// Resize Image
$image_output = get_resized_image_output( array( "image_url" => $cat_image_url , "image_id" => "", "w" => $w, "h" => $h, "crop" => $crop ) ); 

?>

<div class="product_item_holder product-showcase-category">

    <?php if( ! empty( $image_output ) && $display_thumbnails == "true" ):?>
        <!-- product image -->
        <div class="featured_image"> 
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $rt_category ); ?>" title="<?php echo $rt_category->cat_name; ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo $image_output;?>
                <?php if( $display_titles != "true" && $display_descriptions != "true" ) : ?><span class="category-name"><?php echo $rt_category->cat_name;?> (<?php echo $rt_category->count ?>)</span></a><?php endif;?>
        </div> 
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if( $display_titles == "true" || $display_descriptions == "true" ) : ?>
    <div class="product_info">

        <?php if( $display_titles == "true" ) : ?>
        <!-- title-->
        <h5 class="clean_heading"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $rt_category ); ?>" title="<?php echo $rt_category->cat_name ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo $rt_category->cat_name ?><span><?php echo $rt_category->count ?></span></a></h5>
        <?php endif;?>

        <!-- text-->
        <?php echo ! empty( $rt_category->description ) && $display_descriptions == "true" ? sprintf( '<p>%s</p>', $rt_category->description ) : "" ; ?>

    </div>
    <?php endif;?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the place where you call this shortcode `rt_product_categories` you can paste arguments inside it.

In argument list

```
$rt_list_atts = shortcode_atts( array(  
        "id"                   => '',
        "class"                => '',
        "ids"                  => '',
        "list_layout"          => "1/3",
        "display_titles"       => "true",       
        "display_descriptions" => "true",       
        "display_thumbnails"   => "true",       
        "image_max_height"     => '',
        "crop"                 => '',
        'orderby'              => 'name',
        "order"                => "ACS",
        'parent'               => 0,
        'layout_style'         => ''
    ), $atts );
```

this line `"list_layout" => "1/3",` controls how many columns will print in your theme page. So if you know where `rt_product_categories` scortcode is called, you can play with it, passing diffrent values for this attribute.

If you don't know where this is hapend, you can hardcode column numbers changing this row

```
$column_count = rt_column_count( $list_layout );
```

to

```
$column_count = 4;
```

I think this also will do the trick.

Comment: Hi, Hardcoding didn't work. Shortcode calls the rttheme19/product-contents/category-shortcode-content.php (i added it to main post)

Comment: I don't have access to this `rttheme19` theme to view all the files, but in the link that you provided above, the number of columns are controled by this variable `$column_count` and with this attribute `data-column-width="'. $column_count .'"` into row div. Following first link you can see that this `data-column-width` on each row is 2, and on the second site it is 4. In `category-shortcode-content.php` file I can't see where this `data-column-width` property is set, so I think that `category-shortcode-content.php` is not the template used for displaying provided page.